# evaluating $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t-\frac{x}{t}}}{t} dt$

Tags: improper-integrals

I got to this integral, while proving some theorem in statistics:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t-\frac{x}{t}}}{t} \mathop{dt}$$

I have trouble evaluating it. I tried partial integration, tried substitution with some polynomial and some trigonometric functions. None of them helped, and Wolfram can't compute it either. Do you have a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps that the beginning of chapter XVII (p.$355$) of [Whittaker & Watson 'A Course Of Modern Analysis'](http://archive.org/details/ACourseOfModernAnalysis) will interest you (from $1927$ but still hard to replace !). The Bessel $J$ function is introduced there with just a little more general integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little help from Maple, the integral is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t-\frac{x}{t}}}{t}\,dt = 2K_0(2\sqrt{x}),$$

where $K_0$ is [the modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) of order zero.

Comment: ouch... So I guess that means I shouldn't be looking for a closed form expression. Right?

Comment: @Untitled There are people who know more about Bessel functions than I do, but I suspect that's as good a closed form as you will get.

Comment: +1: [DLMF 10.32.10](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E10) may be used as a reference for this integral.

Answer (score 1):

It worked on WolframAlpha after I hit the "Extended computation time" button:

[image]