# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-\frac{a}{x})}{(x+\frac{1}{x})}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

for this integral, I plan to solve it by using residues, but it seems when dealing with the integral over the upper semi-circle, it doesn't converge. Could you give some help, thank you very much!
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x-\frac{a}{x})}{(x+\frac{1}{x})}dx$$

Comment: Can you show your execution of your "plan"?  The work behind your conclusion?

Comment: I have a solution, but without using residues. I can answer, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, could you please give some hint without using residues? Thank you :)

Comment: Ah, I think I know how to solve it now, but it still needs to calculate the residues. So could you share your method please? @LaxmiNarayanBhandari

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but at first glance I thought about this: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html

Comment: thank you, and I have solved it by using residues :) @P.TeruoNagasava

Comment: Please, add in the post the solution with residues.

Comment: You can argue that the value of the integral is $\Im \left(2 \pi i \operatorname{Res} \left[\frac{z e^{iz}e^{-ia/z}}{1+z^{2}}, i \right] \right) = \frac{\pi}{e^{a+1}}$ by first showing that $\left|e^{-ia/z}\right| \le 1$  in the upper half plane if $a \ge 0$.  Then use Jordan's lemma.

Comment: It is interesting to mention that the approach proposed by @Random Variable allows to evaluate a more general integral ($a,b>0; c\in R$):
$$I(a,b,c)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ibx-\frac{ia}{x-c}}}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx=\pi i\,e^{-b-\frac{a}{1+c^2}}e^{-i\frac{ac}{1+c^2}}$$
$$I_1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\,(bx-\frac{a}{x-c})}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx=\pi\,e^{-b-\frac{a}{1+c^2}}\cos\Big(\frac{ac}{1+c^2}\Big)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav The last integral isn't possible to evaluate with my approach, though. Complex analysis is much more powerful for such integrals.

Comment: @MathFail, it's quite not nice to remove the question by vandalising it. Some have put effort (and quite a lot!) to answer your question and which most certainly solved the problem and helped you. If so accept it and put back the question as it was. You see, this site not just for individuals, it is also for a Community. So this could help someone else too

Comment: @Vega No, it is not removed, it is closed by system. My post was to ask if it can be solved by contour integral, nothing else... I see, I will accept Laxmi's solution then :)

Comment: You removed the question text by yourself, that's what I was saying. You can still improve your question and vote to reopen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not going to use residues for this. This answer is going to abuse differentiation under the integral sign.

We start by noting that the integrand is even and thus,

$$I (a)=2 \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\sin\big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x+\frac1x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Throughout the solution, I will be assuming that $a \geq 0$.

Differentiating w.r.t. $a$,
$$I'(a) = -2 \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos\big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx $$
Again differentiating,
$$\begin{align}I' '(a) &= -2 \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\sin\big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x(x^2+1)} \,\mathrm dx \\ &= -2 \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\sin\big(x-\frac ax\big)}x-\frac{x\sin \big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx\end{align}$$

Using the substitution $x\mapsto \frac ax$, we can easily prove that $ \int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x-\frac ax)}x=0$. Thus,

$$I' '(a) = 2 \int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x\sin\big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx= I(a) $$

Now, we have a differential equation, cool!

$$\begin{align}I(a) &= I' '(a) \\ \implies I(a) &= k_1 e^a+k_2 e^{-a}  \end{align}$$
For evaluating the constants, we have the initial values $(I(0), I'(0))=\big(\frac\pi e, -\frac\pi e \big)$. Using this, we get $(k_1,k_2)=\big(0,\frac\pi e\big)$.

Thus, we conclude that
$$I(a) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\big(x-\frac ax\big)}{x+\frac1x}\,\mathrm dx = \frac\pi {e^{a+1}} $$

Comment: This is more than impressive !

Comment: A nice approach (+1). Is it possible to evaluate $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin\big(bx-\frac ax\big)}{x+\frac1x}\,\mathrm dx (a,b>0) $ in this way?

Comment: @Claude Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Svyatoslav The procedure will stay the same. Only the zeroing substitution will change to $x\mapsto \frac a{bx}$.

Comment: $$I(a,b)= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x\sin\big(bx-\frac ax\big)}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm dx$$ In the same way as you did (and using your substitution $x\mapsto \frac a{bx}$) $$I(a,b)=k_1e^a+k_2e^{-a}; \,I(a=0,b)=\pi e^{-b}; \,I'_a(a=0,b)=-\pi e^{-b}$$ $$\Rightarrow I(a,b)=\pi e^{-(a+b)}$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Noice.

Comment: Wow, this method is really fantastic!! Thank you so much! @LaxmiNarayanBhandari

Comment: This trick $x->a/x$ let the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x-\frac{a}{x})}{x}dx$ vanish, because inside the sine function it is subtraction, right? It seems if we change the numerator to $\sin(x+\frac{a}{x})$, then this trick seems not work? In this case, must we compute the residues the only way? @LaxmiNarayanBhandari

Comment: You guessed it right. This trick is only useful in this particular case with sine and subtraction between the two fractions. Otherwise, the only way would be to actually compute the integral. The fun fact is that if you evaluate the original, but with cosine instead of sine, you will get exactly the same result. Must try it! @MathFail

Comment: @Math for the arrow sign I have used, use \mapsto . This will give $\mapsto $.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Do the same integral, but with cosine instead of sine.

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x-\frac{a}{x})}{(x+\frac{1}{x})}dx =0$$ - if we integrate $(-\infty; \infty)$ (the integrand is odd). This is also visible from the general case: $$I_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos\,(bx-\frac{a}{x-c})}{x+\frac{1}{x}}dx =\Re \,\pi i\,e^{-b-\frac{a}{1+c^2}}e^{-i\frac{ac}{1+c^2}}=\pi\,e^{-b-\frac{a}{1+c^2}}\sin\Big(\frac{ac}{1+c^2}\Big)$$ $$I_2=0 \,(\text{at} \,c=0)$$ For the integral $(0; \infty)$ it is more complicated; for example, $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos\,(x-\frac{a}{x})}{x}dx\neq0$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I used my method, but on the limits $(0,\infty)$, and I got the same result as the integral with sign. Try my method.

Comment: $$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x-\frac{a}{x})}{(x+\frac{1}{x})}dx$$ $$I''_{aa}=I(a)-\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos\,(x-\frac{a}{x})}{x}dx$$
But the second term is not zero: after the turn in the complex plane ($x=it$)
$$\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\cos\,(x-\frac{a}{x})}{x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-t-\frac{a}{t}}}{t}dt=2K_0(2\sqrt a)$$ - if I made all correctly
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403576/evaluating-int-0-infty-frace-t-fracxtt-dt?noredirect=1)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Probably you are correct. I missed that my method would work on $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x-\frac ax)}{x^2+1}\, dx $. Nice work.